# Display JPanel on JFrame from another class

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

Using NetBeans IDE and Java, neither of which I'm overly familiar with. I have a JFrame laid out with a JPanel on it, and said JPanel has buttons on it. This JPanel is in the JFrames class. When one of these buttons is clicked, I would like to stop displaying this JPanel, and display another JPanel in a different class. I am using the GUI designer hence the panels being in different classes.

The buttonclick event in the JFrame class for one of the buttons I have:

```
    private void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                                         
    panel1.setVisible(false);
    Panel2 panel2 = new Panel2();
    this.add(panel2);
    panel2.setVisible(true);
```

This produces results of the panel1 disappearing however leaving a blank Jframe as panel2 does not display.

I have looked at CardLayout but I need the buttons on the panels to issue commands rather than buttons on another panel swapping around panels of a CardLayout.

EDIT: Have rewritten question to actually provide context and not just "help pls" as I've been told that what I was asking was too broad, which is completely correct. I've only just started learning Java so if this is still to broad  aquestion, apologies.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question... your question is too broad. Actually you don't have a specific question, you rather have the need that an experienced person sits down with you to discuss your idea, and to outline a solution, and who follows up with you during the 10, 20 steps required to get that working. But that is not what this community is for.

Comment: Fair enough you are right. I'm just a bit frustrated as everything I've attempted so far has left me with a non-working app so this was kind of a last-ditch effort. I'll try to provide an edit that is more specific.

Comment: I understand such frustration. Maybe you have to focus a bit more on "basic" stuff. Instead of trying to turn your own vision / idea into a GUI app ... get a good book or tutorial, and first work through a complete example that others give you. Sure, it is not your idea then, but especially when doing GUI programming: there are a zillions of things you have to know in order to get it to do what you want to do. One subtle mistake, and the whole UI is messed up. Gaining that experience by trial and error is terribly hard. First gain experience by following a complete tutorial ... step by step.

Comment: I have been that's why I'm here. I've been trial and error-ing for so long and I've not some to any concrete assertions as to where I'm going wrong or what I should be doing. I am currently rewriting to question with some context so as to not seem like a lost schoolkid.

Comment: Have updated question!

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try to help a bit here ...

First of all, it is not a good idea to do more than "almost" nothing in action listener code. Especially *instantiating* a new panel object within that listener is a bad idea.

A more reasonable approach: create all your panel objects **up front**. Like: when your application comes up, maybe have a list of the required panel objects. And then, within your action listener code, simply add the one that needs to show up, and remove the one that isn't required any more.

Also note:

- anything you "do" within an action listener happens on the event dispatcher thread (go google that term). here, that is probably what you want, but very often, it is not.
- just calling setVisible() isn't enough. You might have to trigger the layout manager to do a repaint. Thus decide for a specific layout manager, and research that dynamically adding/hiding of components.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm just going to use JFrames and tabbed panels for now which I know isn't the best practise but does the job. With regards to instantiating things, I did have at one point the panel being instantiated in the onload method, and then set the visibility of panels in the button click. This hid the first panel but didn't show the second, do I need extra code somewhere else to provide context or size etc?

Answer (score 0):

i recomend to dispose the frame1 and set frame2 visible   , where frame1 contaions the first panel and frame2 contains the second panel and i did not make the JButton btw just gave a solution , i did not compile it but i recommend doing something similar to this.

```
JFrame frame1;
JFrame frame2;
JPanel panel1;
JPanel panel2;

public ClassName() {
    frame1 = new JFrame("FIRST FRAME NAME");
    frame2 = new JFrame("SECOND FRAME NAME");

    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setSize(WIDTH , HEIGHT);
    frame1.add(panel1);
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame2.setSize(WIDTH , HEIGHT);
    frame2.add(panel2);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}

 private void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                                         
    frame1.dispose();
    frame2.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ClassName();
}
```

Comment: Hi @EpicCircles - welcome to Stack Overflow.  This answer seems alot like the accepted answer (from 2years ago) - although you have put a code snippet in and are suggesting to use JFrames (effectively wiindows) rather than just show / hide panels (and the code snippet looks like it mightn't work - how is the action method hooked up) ?  Would you consider updating the accepted answer with the extra details?

Comment: i posted what i think you looking for

Answer (score 0):

is this what your looking for ?

```
package project3;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class File2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    JPanel panel1;
    JPanel panel2;
    JButton button;
    JLabel label;
    
    public File2() {
        
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        
        button = new JButton("CLICK ME");
        label = new JLabel("I AM A LABEL");
        
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        panel1.add(button);
        panel2.add(label);
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400 , 400);
        this.add(panel2);
        this.add(panel1);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new File2();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        panel1.setVisible(false);
        this.remove(panel1);
        this.add(panel2);
        
    }

}
```